# Edges won't join / UV unwrap issue Blender 2.8

Tags: uv, edges

Started unwrapping my model, and ran into a couple issues. I think i found problem, but could use some help fixing it.

The unwrap is extremely warped in various spots of the mesh. While attempting to troubleshoot the issue I found edges are not properly connected to each other in between extrusions(you'll see what I mean when opening the file). I attempted to join those edges with no luck. It seems there is something I'm missing. Problem area is marked in blue circle.

[image: Problem area]

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others downloading the file and maybe understanding what the issue is. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Unwrapping is not as simple as you'd like it to be. Using software like Substance Painter allows me to be lazy and just UV-Smart Unwrap the entire model at once. To do it properly however takes a long time. I suggest watching some tutorials at first. You are not doing anything wrong and there really isn't a way to answer your question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MckPa3qbu9A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that you get better results when UV unwrapping your model if you use the Conformal method.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Still learning 2.8. I remember an add-on being required for results like this, right?